# Unable fetch the api's data

Tags: angular, api, model, angular-services

I have an component called `customer` which is used to display some data using the  **api**.

> For calling the `api` i have created a file called `services.ts` and it's CODE looks like this:

**services.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IPosts } from './models';

@Injectable()
  export class Service {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   public getContactList(): Promise<IPosts> {
    const apiUrl: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'; // dummy API

    return this.http.get<IPosts>(apiUrl).toPromise();
   }
 }
```

> As shown in the code an `interface` (IPosts),I have declared this interface(i,e IPosts)  inside an file called `models.ts`. The CODE looks like this:

```
   export interface IPosts {
    userId: number;
    id:     number;
    title:  string;
    body:   string;
    }
```

> Now i am displaying this `api's` data in`customer` component is like this:

**customer.html**

```
   <div class="container">
        <h3>Blog Posts:</h3>
      <div class="blogPost " *ngFor = "let post of posts">
           <p>{{post.title}}</p>
           <p>{{post.body}}</p>
           <hr>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**customer.ts**

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { Service } from '../service';
  import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
  import { IPosts } from '../models';

  @Component({
   selector: 'app-customer',
   templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
  })

  export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
          constructor(public customersServiceList: Service) {}

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    const posts : IPosts = await this.customersServiceList.getContactList();
    console.log(posts);
    }

  }
```

I am able see the api's data in the console:

[image]

But unable to display it in `.html` file . What's wrong in calling the `api`. 
Here is the stckblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-service-demo-with-api-9cgeyn?file=app/customer/customer.component.ts)**

Comment: i think, you need to use that const in `this.data = posts` and use data in `ngFor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **CustomerComponent** like this

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public customersServiceList: Service) {}
  posts : IPosts[];
  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
      this.posts  = await this.customersServiceList.getContactList();
      console.log(this.posts);
   }
 }
```

**Service**

```
 public getContactList(): Promise<IPosts[]> {

    const apiUrl: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    return this.http.get<IPosts[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
  }
```

It's working check here [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8es9b5?file=src/app/Customer/customer.component.ts)

Comment: your declaring const in method level, Otherthan that it's fine. Glad to help :)

Comment: You have not given proper  link `stckblitz` word , please check it once..:)

Answer (score 2):

Without `async` call you can use `.then` to get the response from API service:

In HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Blog Posts:</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="blogPost " *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <p>{{post.title}}</p>
    <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

In TS file:

```
posts: any;
constructor(public customersServiceList: Service) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.customersServiceList.getContactList().then(response => {
    if (response) {
      this.posts = response;
    }
 });

}
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-service-demo-with-api-uwqsqt)

Answer (score 1):

> You can often use observables instead of promises to deliver values
>   asynchronously. Similarly, observables can take the place of event
>   handlers. Finally, because observables deliver multiple values, you
>   can use them where you might otherwise build and operate on
>   arrays.(from Angular.io)

check this [link](https://angular.io/guide/comparing-observables)

can change like this--
**CustomerComponent**

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private customersServiceList: Service) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  public getPosts(){
    this.customersServiceList.getContactList().subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res[0].title);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error.error);
  });
  }

}
```

**Service**

```
export class Service {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }


  public  getContactList(): Observable<IPosts[]> {
    const apiUrl: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

    return this.http.get<IPosts[]>(apiUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance..:)